# Understanding the copy constructor and references

Tags: c++

I have troubles uderstanding the concept of the copy constructor and also of references:

Here's an example that I found:

```
class Person {
private: 
    string *name;
    int age;

public: 
    Person(string name, int age) {
        this -> name = new string(name);
        this -> age = age;
    }
}
```

I understand the code as follows: the constructor is given the parameters `name`and `age`. When, in the `main()`function, an object of class Person is created, the constructor will be invoked and `this` returns the address of the object. I think. At this address now, a variable `name` will be created, by using `new`the necessasry memory will be allocated. Also, afterwards I think, a variable age is stored at the current memory address.

Okay, now the copy constructor is implemented:

```
Person(const Person &p) {
    name = new string(*p.name);
    age = p.age;
}
```

When, in the `main()`, an assignment of two objects of class Person is done, the copy constructor will be invoked:

```
Person Person1(Lukas, 25);
Person Person2 = Person1;
```

So, I get that this is needed in order to perform a deep copy instead of a shallow copy. But what happens in this assignment? If the copy constructor gets called, Person1 will be the parameter of it. This is supposed to be a reference. What oes d mean? Until now, I figured, a reference simply gives an alias of a variable, but in this assignment, Person1 is an existing variable, it is no reference!

Comment: It's not assignment. It's (copy-)initialization. Just like `int i = 1;` is

Comment: As a side note, in C++ your constructor is usually written as: `Person(std::string name, int age): name(new std::string(std::move(name))), age(age) {}`. And yes, `Person1` IS a reference when used as a RHS of initialization.

Comment: I suggest finding a good C++ book.

Comment: It may help you (or may not) to realise that your second line of code could also be called as `Person Person2(Person1);`

Comment: A reference *is*  an alias, that is correct. But the reference is `p`, not anything else. So inside the copy constructor `p` is an alias for `Person1`.

Comment: Do you really need to allocate a `string` on the heap?

Comment: @MikeBorkland He doesn't.

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz  I know. That was my point.

Comment: Just to be clear: `string *name;` really ought to be `string name;` and `name = new string(*p.name);` really ought to be `name = p.name`.  However, once you've gotten rid of any superfluous pointers and `new`s, you can instead have `Person(const Person&) = default;` which will give you an [implicitly-declared copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), which will handle the deep copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've distilled this as your actual question:

> But what happens in this assignment? If the copy constructor gets called, Person1 will be the parameter of it. This is supposed to be a reference. What oes d mean?

And the answer is actually pretty straightforward. You've mentioned that:

> I figured, a reference simply gives an alias of a variable

And this is correct. Consider:

```
int x = 42;
int& y = x;
cout << y; // prints 42
```

It works the same in functions:

```
int x = 42;

void print(int& y) {
    cout << y;
}
print(x); // prints 42
```

And since the copy constructor is just a special function, it works just the same:

```
Person a;
Person b = a;

// Inside:
Person(const Person& p) {
    // p is an alias for "a"
    // "this" is referencing "b"
}
```

The constructor has a way to access both the object copied from (by the ref parameter) and the object copied to (by `this`), so it can do all the necessary copying, be it deep or shallow.